# Parsing "OTHER" ASN.1 types with OpenSSL 1.1 API

Tags: c, openssl

I'm trying to understand how to deal with parsing ASN.1 types with application specific contents. Given a rather simple schema:

```
World-Schema DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= 
BEGIN
  Rocket ::= SEQUENCE       
  {                                                     
     name      IA5String,
     type      IA5String
  }                                                     
END
```

And data:

```
value Rocket ::= {
  name "Falcon",
  type "Boo"
}
```

(I use http://asn1-playground.oss.com/ to generate serialized DER data).

I can get the outer container with a d2i function:

```
ASN1_SEQUENCE_ANY * container = d2i_ASN1_SEQUENCE_ANY(0, (const unsigned char**)&ptr, (long)len);
ASN1_TYPE * el = sk_ASN1_TYPE_value(container, 0);
```

That `el` is has a type of -3, which is `V_ASN1_OTHER`, which is correct for my schema. But I'm banging my head against the wall on how to, using ASN.1 API, drill into the contents, that are IA5Strings. I believe the contents are in `el->value.asn1_value`, but I'm not supposed to access that directly (the type is opaque to me), and I'm only considering functions that are in https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/. Is there also any document(ation) that explains how it should be done?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSL documentation is rather limited when it comes to the ASN.1 functionality. The best way to learn about it is by inspecting the associated header files [`asn1.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0i/include/openssl/asn1.h) and [`asn1t.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0i/include/openssl/asn1t.h), which are public. They define a set of macros that allow you to create your own ASN.1 types. Again, looking at the source code is the best way to understand how those are used, for example in [`ts_asn1.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0i/crypto/ts/ts_asn1.c). A rudimentary explanation is given in [ASN1_ITEM()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/ASN1_ITEM.html). Have fun!

Fortunately, your example `Rocket` type is simple. Its ASN.1 type definition with helper functions can be created as follows:

```
/* Rocket.h */
#include <openssl/asn1.h>

typedef struct Rocket_st {
    ASN1_IA5STRING *name;
    ASN1_IA5STRING *type;
} ROCKET;

DECLARE_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(ROCKET)
```

The structure is hand-coded, the `DECLARE_ASN1_FUNCTIONS` macro expands to a set of helper functions that get implemented in the following way:

```
/* Rocket.c */
#include "Rocket.h"
#include <openssl/asn1t.h>

ASN1_SEQUENCE(ROCKET) = {
        ASN1_SIMPLE(ROCKET, name, ASN1_IA5STRING),
        ASN1_SIMPLE(ROCKET, type, ASN1_IA5STRING),
} ASN1_SEQUENCE_END(ROCKET)

IMPLEMENT_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(ROCKET)
```

After compilation, the symbol table looks like this (I am using a Mac):

```
$ objdump -t Rocket.o

Rocket.o:   file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000000000d0 l       __DATA,__const _ROCKET_seq_tt
00000000000000a0 g     F __TEXT,__text  _ROCKET_free
0000000000000120 g       __DATA,__const _ROCKET_it
0000000000000080 g     F __TEXT,__text  _ROCKET_new
0000000000000000 g     F __TEXT,__text  _d2i_ROCKET
0000000000000040 g     F __TEXT,__text  _i2d_ROCKET
0000000000000000         *UND*  _ASN1_IA5STRING_it
0000000000000000         *UND*  _ASN1_item_d2i
0000000000000000         *UND*  _ASN1_item_free
0000000000000000         *UND*  _ASN1_item_i2d
0000000000000000         *UND*  _ASN1_item_new
```

The undefined symbols are provided by the OpenSSL `crypto` library. You can use the functions with `ROCKET` in their name for back and forth conversion between C-structured and DER-serialized data. Some more information about the `d2i` and `i2d` functions can be found in the OpenSSL documentation page called [`d2i_X509`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/d2i_X509.html). Your application code could look like something along these lines:

```
ROCKET *rocket;
ROCKET *rocket2;
unsigned char *rocketString;
const unsigned char *ptr;
int len;

rocket = ROCKET_new();
rocket->name = ASN1_IA5STRING_new();
ASN1_STRING_set(rocket->name, "Falcon", -1);
rocket->type = ASN1_IA5STRING_new();
ASN1_STRING_set(rocket->type, "Boo", -1);

len = i2d_ROCKET(rocket, &rocketString);
printf("DER-encoded Rocket has length %d\n", len);

ptr = rocketString;
rocket2 = d2i_ROCKET(NULL, &ptr, len);
printf("rocket2 fields are:\n  name = \"%s\"\n  type = \"%s\"\n",
   ASN1_STRING_get0_data(rocket2->name),
   ASN1_STRING_get0_data(rocket2->type));
```

The result:

```
$ ./main
DER-encoded Rocket has length 15
rocket2 fields are:
  name = "Falcon"
  type = "Boo"
```

Comment: Thank you. In essence, this means - can't drill down using low-level functions, have to define your ASN.1 structures, so the low level part is handled by OpenSSL.

Comment: In the end, the `IMPLEMENT_ASN1_FUNCTIONS` template expands to code that you could disseminate and reproduce in your own application. It uses the low-level functions `ASN1_item_d2i()` and `ASN1_item_i2d()`. With the provided code snippet, you could use a debugger to see what is going on, or you could just inspect the OpenSSL source code. I do not think that would be the intended way to use those functions though.